# Why did the SLS only reach a TLI speed of 17500 mph

Tags: sls

Why did the SLS only reach a TLI speed of 17500 mph when the Saturn V reached a TLI speed of 24500?  The SLS was considerably lighter and had 15% more thrust and should have been able to achieve a higher speed.

Comment: Because Apollo didn't take the most efficient route to the Moon. The Apollo missions burned harder on  LEO departure to get to the Moon in about 3 days,  whereas the Artemis missions are taking a Hohmann transfer course, which takes 5-6. Thrust isn't the issue here, it's [delta-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v).

Comment: Also, your numbers are wrong.  You've listed orbital velocity for LEO instead of the TLI speed for SLS.

Comment: @notovny it's not even doing a Hohmann transfer to the moon, it's transferring to NRHO, a L2 halo orbit...specifically because it's easier to reach.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff: Artemis I (which I assume is what the OP is talking about, since I don’t know of another launch of SLS so far) was a distant retrograde orbit, not NRHO. Artemis II will be a free return trajectory.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's right...I'd disregarded that because it's never going to be repeated, but the question does say "did" and "was", so seems to be about the first launch, not typical operations. The distant retrograde orbit was a similarly high, relatively accessible orbit, though, entered and departed via lunar powered flybys to reduce the propulsive delta-v needed.

Answer (score 5):

An hour and twenty minutes after being inserted into low Earth orbit at 17,175 mph (27,640 km/h), the Artemis I SLS Interim Cryogenic Propulsion Stage (ICPS) performed the Trans-Lunar Injection (TLI) burn which accelerated the Orion spacecraft towards the Moon at a velocity of about 22,600 mph (36,371 km/h).

According to [Apollo by the Numbers](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029.pdf) the velocity after the TLI burn performed by the Saturn S-IVB stage ranged from 24,129 mph (38,832 km/h) for Apollo 12, to 24,258 mph (39,039 km/h) for Apollo 15.

The Apollo and Artemis I missions used different trajectories to reach the Moon. The Saturn V TLI burns placed the Apollo spacecraft on a less efficient three-day trajectory, which was also a free-return trajectory that would have looped around the Moon and returned to Earth if a Lunar Orbit Insertion (LOI) burn was not performed by the Apollo spacecraft. This provided a safety margin in case a problem occurred during the trip to the Moon (as actually happened on Apollo 13).

[image: Apollo 8 trajectory]
Apollo 8, ([NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/history/55-years-ago-eight-months-before-the-moon-landing/))

A slightly modified trajectory was used starting with Apollo 12 and all subsequent lunar missions. Besides the LOI burn a mid-course correction burn was also required to "cancel" the free-return trajectory. This method opened up a larger area of potential landing sites, while still allowing time to check out the spacecraft systems prior to committing to a non-return trajectory.

Artemis I was a non-crewed mission which used a very different trajectory than was used on the Apollo lunar missions, as well as being different from what will be used on the crewed Artemis II and Artemis III flights. Artemis I used a more efficient five-day trajectory to reach the Moon, and was not free-return. Two post TLI burns performed by the Orion spacecraft (not counting course corrections) placed Orion into a Distant Retrograde Orbit.

[image: Artemis I trajectory]
Artemis I ([NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/image-article/artemis-i-map-2/))

Artemis II will be a crewed non-landing, non-orbiting mission and will use a free-return trajectory. However like Artemis I it will take more than three days for Artemis II to reach the Moon using a more efficient trajectory than Apollo. After separating from the ICPS the Orion spacecraft will make several burns on the way to the Moon as part of a Multi-Trans-Lunar Injection (MTLI) method.

[image: Artemis II trajectory]
Artemis II ([NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/image-article/artemis-ii-map-2/))

For Artemis III Orion will be placed into a Near-Rectilinear Halo Orbit (NRHO) where the the crew will transfer to the Starship HLS lunar lander.

[image: Artemis III trajectory]
Artemis III ([NASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_3#/media/File:Artemis_III_Mission_profile_2025.jpg))

#### Additional Info:

The Artemis I 17,175 mph LEO number is from the [NASA TV live broadcast commentary](https://www.youtube.com/live/CMLD0Lp0JBg?si=0FarPcW6a30brVKs) (timestamp 3:36:16) on November 16, 2022

The Artemis I 22,600 mph TLI number is based on the following sources:

[NASA pre-launch document](https://www.nasa.gov/humans-in-space/space-launch-system/the-great-escape-sls-provides-power-for-missions-to-the-moon-duzxi/) - 24,500 mph
[NASA TV live broadcast commentary](https://www.youtube.com/live/CMLD0Lp0JBg?si=0FarPcW6a30brVKs) (timestamp 5:00:22) November 16, 2022 -  22,500 mph
[CNN Interactive](https://www.cnn.com/interactive/2022/11/world/artemis-1-mission-explainer/) November 16, 2022 - 22,600
[CollectSpace](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-111622a-artemis-i-orion-trans-lunar-injection-tli.html) November 16, 2022 -  22,670

Apollo TLI (from [Apollo by the Numbers](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029.pdf))

| Mission | mph | km/h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apollo 8 | 24,208 | 38,959 |
| Apollo 10 | 24,247 | 39,022 |
| Apollo 11 | 24,236 | 39,004 |
| Apollo 12 | 24,129 | 38,832 |
| Apollo 13 | 24,231 | 38,996 |
| Apollo 14 | 24,212 | 38,965 |
| Apollo 15 | 24,258 | 39,039 |
| Apollo 16 | 24,250 | 39,027 |
| Apollo 17 | 24,242 | 39,014 |